# Layout format for Android

Tags: android, layout, formatting

I'm pretty new to the Android scene and I'm having troubles creating an UI for my program.

Since I can't post a picture of my target I'm going to describe what I actually planned:

- My Ui should be divided into 3 parts. Whereas the upper part takes like 25% of the sreen. - The middle part takes 60% and the bottom part takes 15%.
- The middle part is divided into 2 columns. The first column takes 70% and the second one 30%.
- On the top part i just want to add some buttons.
- In the middle on the left column (which takes 70%) I wanted to add a SurfaceView.
- On the right part I thought of some panel with buttons to navigate through my app.
- The bottom part should be empty.

So I was wondering first of all, how to get the scaling done?

I thought of LinearLayout weights but I couldn't come up with the proper numbers.

With a RelativeLayout I wasn't sure how the fill the SurfaceView in properly.

Comment: You need to use "android:orientation" and "android:layout_weight" features

Comment: @yygyt that really doesn't help... he says he already tried with LinearLayout but he couldn't get it to work. And the orientation thing is not directly related with the question.

Comment: The fact he didn't get it to work dosen't mean that it won't. I suggest you solve your issues with LinearLayout as this seems like an easier solution to me. try posting your code and let us check out what's wrong with it.

Comment: @lxx I am recommending him to search through internet using the keywords provided. But if I need to clarify he says that UI should be divided into 3 parts. Here he can use "android:orientation="vertical"" and he also says that "The middle part is divided into 2 columns" he can use "android:orientation="horizontal"" there. I think "weight" is self-explanatory.

Comment: yeah, I just mean, he says "I thought of LinearLayout weights but couldn't bla bla", and then he gets a comment "You need to use LinearLayout weights". Well, yes, the comment is not completly useless, but pretty much incomplete.

Comment: Is there a possibility to get scaling right with weights? If i use layout_weight 1 on each one with will be 1/3. This case worked for me however i dont know which wheights would make that scaling: 25% 60% 15%

Comment: Alright i somehwat read about the calculation.To get the right scaling i should set my sumofweights 20 and weight the first one 5 the second one 12 and the third 3 and it will work right? Like: 5/20 (25%) + 12/20 (60%) + 3/20 (15%)

Comment: @StuPitt I posted an answer. I used weights in the answer for a layout of mine to divide the screen 20% 40% 40%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using nested *LinearLayouts*

```
<LinearLayout ...>
    ....
    <LinearLayout...>
```

For the weight part, I once used that attribute as follows

```
    <EditText
        ...
        android:layout_weight="1"
        .../>

<EditText
        ...
        android:layout_weight="2"
        ... />

<EditText
        ...
        android:layout_weight="2"
        ... />
```

You need to look at [android:orientation attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3aorientation)  too.

You also may want to use [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)

Comment: Like i posted above i have to set the sumofweights right to get my scaling mentioned above. Would it work ?

Comment: I haven't tried but use 5, 12 and 3 as weights and tell me what happens.